# Cross between a contact form and upload file form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm working on a file upload form that I would like to do 3 specific things.  Maybe it's late and I'm an amateur coder so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what needs to be done here.

- I need help making the upload form email me when a file is uploaded, nothing fancy.
- I need help making the uploaded file make a new directory of www.mywebsite.com/uploads/`$client`. (which will be filled in in the form)
- I need help making sure the form has the required information filled out before being ready to submit (email, name, file chosen).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 <?php 
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];    
$extension = strtolower(substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1));
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$max_file_size = 34000000;
$client = $_POST['client'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "test@test.com";
$subject = "File upload from:";
$mailheader = "From:" . $email;


    if (isset($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {

        if (($size<=$max_file_size)) {

        $location = '../uploads/';
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)); {
                echo 'File uploaded :)';
            }
        } else {
            echo('File type not accepted.  File size must be 30mb or less.');
        }
    } else {
        echo('Please choose a file before hitting submit');
    }
    }

    ?>
```

I thank you all for any help you may offer!

Answer (score 1):

PHP email  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

PHP create directory - http://php.net/mkdir

jquery form validation - http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

These Google searches are killing me :P

Answer (score 1):

It will be a very long answer to the questions. I'll try to give some short but useful hints.

1. Sending mail you can use [mail function](http://www.php.net/mail) but bad things can happen like it may be marked as spam by your mail provider.
2. Making new directory you can use [mkdir function](http://www.php.net/mkdir). You can check if the directory [exists](http://www.php.net/file-exists) before mkdir.
3. Form validation you need to learn javascript, and maybe jQuery, or make use of some *javascript form validation framework*.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$max_file_size = 34000000;
$client = $_POST['client'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if($client!='' && $email!=''){
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if($filename!=''){
        $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['size']);
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
        if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" || $extension=="png" ){
            if( $size <= $file_size_limit){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],"upload/" .date("d_m_h_i_s"). $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            }else {
                echo 'Max File Uplode size Error';
            }
        } else{
         echo 'Invalid File Type';
        }
    } else {
    echo 'Please insert a file';
    }
} else {
 echo 'Please enter the details';
}


function getExtension($str){
    $i = strrpos($str,".")
    if (!$i){
        return "";
    }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}
?>
```

i haven't tested it . you need to now use the details in mail function. The files are checked based on extention & size. I hope you are using method as POST & enctype="multipart/form-data" for form upload. Try using email validation using JS also

Comment: This didn't really get me to where I want to go but I think I've made progress since I posted the question! :)